# Spring Boot 2. Во время запуска netflix Eureka Client выдаётся эксепшен Cannot execute request on any known server

Tags: java, spring-boot

Eureka server - работает. При открытии указанного в properties линка (http://localhost:8761/eureka/) - открывается Eureka dashboard.

Далее хочу зарегистрировать в еврике клиента. Но когда запускаю клиентский проект, в консоль валится эксепшен com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server

Код рабочего Eureka Server:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaServer
public class EurekaServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(EurekaServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties сервера

```
server.port=8761
server.servlet.context-path=/eureka
eureka.client.register-with-eureka=false
eureka.client.fetch-registry=false
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

часть из pom файла сервера

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>
```

Код не рабочего Eureka Client

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableEurekaClient
public class PlayerLifeTrackingServiceApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(PlayerLifeTrackingServiceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

application.properties клиента

```
server.port=8083
spring.application.name=player-life-tracking-service
eureka.instance.hostname=localhost
eukera.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

част pom файла клиента

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.4.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
<properties>
    <java.version>8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Greenwich.SR1</spring-cloud.version>
</properties>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Эксепшен в консоли клиента:

```
019-05-01 12:51:42.715  INFO 11320 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML encoding codec XStreamXml
2019-05-01 12:51:42.715  INFO 11320 --- [           main] c.n.d.provider.DiscoveryJerseyProvider   : Using XML decoding codec XStreamXml
2019-05-01 12:51:42.884  INFO 11320 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.r.aws.ConfigClusterResolver      : Resolving eureka endpoints via configuration
2019-05-01 12:51:42.931  INFO 11320 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Disable delta property : false
2019-05-01 12:51:42.931  INFO 11320 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Single vip registry refresh property : null
2019-05-01 12:51:42.931  INFO 11320 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Force full registry fetch : false
2019-05-01 12:51:42.931  INFO 11320 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application is null : false
2019-05-01 12:51:42.931  INFO 11320 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Registered Applications size is zero : true
2019-05-01 12:51:42.931  INFO 11320 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Application version is -1: true
2019-05-01 12:51:42.931  INFO 11320 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : Getting all instance registry info from the eureka server
2019-05-01 12:51:43.248  WARN 11320 --- [           main] c.n.d.s.t.d.RetryableEurekaHttpClient    : Request execution failure with status code 404; retrying on another server if available
2019-05-01 12:51:43.253 ERROR 11320 --- [           main] com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient    : DiscoveryClient_PLAYER-LIFE-TRACKING-SERVICE/192.168.0.100:player-life-tracking-service:8083 - was unable to refresh its cache! status = Cannot execute request on any known server

com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.TransportException: Cannot execute request on any known server
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.RetryableEurekaHttpClient.execute(RetryableEurekaHttpClient.java:112) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator$6.execute(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:137) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.SessionedEurekaHttpClient.execute(SessionedEurekaHttpClient.java:77) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.shared.transport.decorator.EurekaHttpClientDecorator.getApplications(EurekaHttpClientDecorator.java:134) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.getAndStoreFullRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:1051) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.fetchRegistry(DiscoveryClient.java:965) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:414) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient.<init>(DiscoveryClient.java:269) ~[eureka-client-1.9.8.jar:1.9.8]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.CloudEurekaClient.<init>(CloudEurekaClient.java:67) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration.eurekaClient(EurekaClientAutoConfiguration.java:330) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$83291e71.CGLIB$eurekaClient$0(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$83291e71$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$264a4bf2.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.EurekaClientAutoConfiguration$RefreshableEurekaClientConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$83291e71.eurekaClient(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$1(AbstractBeanFactory.java:356) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$BeanLifecycleWrapper.getBean(GenericScope.java:389) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope.get(GenericScope.java:186) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:353) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getTargetObject(EurekaRegistration.java:129) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration.getEurekaClient(EurekaRegistration.java:117) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.invokeMethod(ReflectionUtils.java:282) ~[spring-core-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.context.scope.GenericScope$LockedScopedProxyFactoryBean.invoke(GenericScope.java:499) ~[spring-cloud-context-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:688) ~[spring-aop-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaRegistration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$5d1d0103.getEurekaClient(<generated>) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.maybeInitializeClient(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:57) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaServiceRegistry.register(EurekaServiceRegistry.java:38) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.eureka.serviceregistry.EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.start(EurekaAutoServiceRegistration.java:83) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-eureka-client-2.1.1.RELEASE.jar:2.1.1.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:182) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$200(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:53) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:360) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:158) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:122) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:893) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.finishRefresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:163) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:552) ~[spring-context-5.1.6.RELEASE.jar:5.1.6.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:142) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:775) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:397) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:316) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1260) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1248) ~[spring-boot-2.1.4.RELEASE.jar:2.1.4.RELEASE]
    at com.flamelab.playerlifetrackingservice.PlayerLifeTrackingServiceApplication.main(PlayerLifeTrackingServiceApplication.java:11) ~[classes/:na]
```

Я прошелся по очень многим сайтам, перепробовал много всяких вариаций настроек. Подскажите пожалуйста, что я недоуказал или неправильно написал, чтобы Eureka Client был зарегистрирован в Eureka Server?

Answer (score 1):

Кому-то пригодится ответ на этот вопрос.
В итоге, дело только в application.properties (теперь переписан на yml)

В серверном настроечном файле убрал server.servlet.context-path=/eureka и теперь файл выглядит так:
    server:
      port: 8761

```
spring:
  application:
    name: LARPTrackerEurekaService

eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: false
    fetch-registry: false
```

В клиентском настроечном файле server.servlet.context-path=/plts

```
server:
  port: 8083
  servlet:
    context-path: /plts

spring:
  application:
    name: player-life-tracking-service

eureka:
  instance:
    hostname: localhost
    preferIpAddress: true
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka
```

Итогово, проблема была в том, что клиент сам дописывал /eukera и ходил на http://localhost:8761/eureka/eureka 
А там естественно никакой еврики не было.